# Parse ID3 tags from MP3 file using MP3SPI

Tags: java, audio, mp3, javasound

I am using [MP3SPI](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html) to play MP3 files in my Java application. It works great to start and stop playing. However, I would want to be able to print ID3 tags from the MP3 files.

I have tried the following code:

```
URL fileUrl = new File("song.mp3").toURI().toURL();

AudioFileFormat audioFileFormat = new MpegAudioFileReader().getAudioFileFormat(fileUrl);
Map<String, Object> properties = audioFileFormat.properties();
for (Entry<String, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) 
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

This code reads the audio file properties and prints out the keys and values of each. It works with everything but the ID3 tags. I have verified that *song.mp3* really has ID3 tags. Running the code above yields the following output:

```
mp3.copyright = false
mp3.framesize.bytes = 1041
mp3.vbr = false
mp3.frequency.hz = 44100
mp3.framerate.fps = 38.28125
mp3.id3tag.v2 = java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@281e3708
mp3.channels = 2
mp3.vbr.scale = 0
mp3.version.encoding = MPEG1L3
mp3.bitrate.nominal.bps = 320000
mp3.version.layer = 3
mp3.id3tag.v2.version = 2
mp3.padding = true
mp3.id3tag.encoded = iTunes 10.6.1
mp3.header.pos = 2147
comment = TunNORM
mp3.version.mpeg = 1
mp3.mode = 0
mp3.crc = false
mp3.original = false
```

According to MP3SPI's documentation and various answers here on Stack Overflow, there should also be properties like *genre* and *artist*. It feels like there is something major I haven't understood, and I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Having *mp3.id3tag.v2* a `ByteArrayInputReader` seems a little odd to me, and I can't figure out what that implies. Also, I have wondered if the fact that the ID3 tags seem to have been encoded with iTunes (looking at *mp3.id3tag.encoded*) has anything to do with not getting any ID3 tag output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly read ID3 tags, use a library like [JAudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/).